# Angular router navigate is not working if page is refreshed

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to redirect user using router but I have a problem.

If I refresh my login page and try to use `router.navigate(['/home'])` or `router.navigateByUrl('/home')` it does not work but if my page is loaded at first time it works.
What I'm doing wrong ??

EDIT

***`authentication.service.ts`***:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private _router: Router,
    ...
  ) {
...

}

public navigateToDashboard() {
    ...
    //this._router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

Thanks.

EDIT 2

***console logs:***

```
2021-04-29T14:35:44.332Z DEBUG [./src/app/core/services/authentication/authentication.service.ts:125] redirect to home logger.service.ts:130:16
2021-04-29T14:35:44.334Z DEBUG [./src/app/app.component.ts:27] Router Event: 
Object { id: 3, url: "/home", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null }
logger.service.ts:130:16
2021-04-29T14:35:44.338Z DEBUG [./src/app/app.component.ts:27] Router Event: 
Object { id: 3, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: {…} }
logger.service.ts:130:16
2021-04-29T14:35:44.340Z DEBUG [./src/app/app.component.ts:27] Router Event: 
Object { id: 3, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: {…} }
logger.service.ts:130:16
2021-04-29T14:35:44.342Z DEBUG [./src/app/app.component.ts:27] Router Event: 
Object { snapshot: {…} }
logger.service.ts:130:16
2021-04-29T14:35:44.344Z DEBUG [./src/app/app.component.ts:27] Router Event: 
Object { snapshot: {…} }
logger.service.ts:130:16

​
```

Comment: Can you add your routes and login `ts` file?

Comment: Do you have any errors? What happens when you try to redirect?

Comment: @BojanKogoj no I don't have any errors and nothing happened. But it not work only if I refresh my login page before I'm trying to redirect

Comment: If you try to refresh your page, it won't work, otherwise `this._router.navigate(['/home']);` will direct you to `http://localhost:4200/home` (if your site is served at `localhost:4200`).

Comment: @StPaulis but it don't work if i refresh my page before trying to redirect with `this._router.navigate(['/home']);`

Comment: There are a lot of thing that maybe goes wrong. A guard maybe block the operation, or you may haven't create your routes well. You can put the code below in your `app.component.ts` to watch all the router events and debug: ```this._router.events.subscribe((e) => console.log(e))``` . You may want to share more info about your current implementation.

Comment: @StPaulis thank you for your help, I can see in logs that it try to redirect but browser not redirect (I edit my post with logs).

Comment: Which is your active path when you try to navigate?

Comment: When I try to navigate active path is /login. This flow is working: `type /login in navbar -> trying to login -> redirect to /home` but if I do that: `type /login in navbar -> refresh page -> trying to login -> don't redirect do /home`

Comment: The best way to see what is happening in the router is to pass in a config object to the `forRoot`: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing:true})`.